# How to Configure hosting behavior in firebase.json to rewrite URL?

Tags: javascript, firebase, redirect, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

I am developing a web app and hosted all files on Firebase Hosting.

I want when someone type this URL

```
mydomain.com/SomeUsername   //SomeUsername is URL Variable
```

it should open this URL

```
mydomain.com/user/index.html?user=SomeUsername   //SomeUsername is URL Variable
```

I tried this but not working, Its redirecting to 404 Page Not Found.

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/user/index.html?user=:SomeUsername*", 
    "destination": "mydomain.com/:SomeUsername*",
    "type": 301
  }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did the answer below worked for you @Jamshaid Alam? I'm in the exact same situation.

Comment: No, I did it other way

Comment: Can you share it by writing an answer please? It will really help me a lot as I'm a new developer :)

Comment: @AlexArdavin I posted Answer. Do  up vote if this works for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found other solution, When I type `mydomain.com/SomeUsername` It will redirect me to 404.html which is obvious this page is not available. I edited 404.html to redirect to actual page.

404.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      const currentUrl = window.location.href;
      var a = document.createElement('a')
      a.setAttribute('href',currentUrl)
      var uname = a.pathname.replace('/','')
      window.location = "https://yourdomain/user/index.html?username="+uname;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in user/index.html page

```
if(history.replaceState) history.replaceState({}, "", "/username");
```

just to show url look like this `mydomain.com/username`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the "type" from the rewrite as this is a rewrite, not a redirect. Also, try removing the domain name from the destination by changing it from:

```
"mydomain.com/:SomeUsername*"
```

to

```
"/:SomeUsername*"
```

The code should say:

```
 "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/user/index.html?user=:SomeUsername*", 
    "destination": "/:SomeUsername*",
```